# "Office 2010 Add-In: Icons Gallery" - How to extract icons from backstage tab (docx)

Tags: icons, ms-office, office-addins

I downloaded "[Office 2010 Add-In: Icons Gallery](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=21103)" that is docx file with two backstage tabs that hold icons.

How can I extract the icons or use them in my application?

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't do this - that artwork is owned by Microsoft and not licensed for use in other applications. Second of all, read first of all.

Comment: how can i use the icons then (no extraction) in my application? I have my own ribbon and i would like to use images from this gallery !

Comment: Anyone coming from Google search see my answer.. you will save yourself a ton of time. My answer contains links to transparent pngs, so no code necessary!

Comment: "Images are in the ImageMso 0 and ImageMso 1 tabs in the Backstage.". Go to File -> ImageMso 0/ImageMso 1. Sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use ImageMso quite frequently in my Excel development. Having stumbled on another post, I took it a step further and put a package together to visually search, extract and save icons from Microsoft Excel as a file or copy and paste (with alpha channel transparency) to another application. I also compiled a list of 8,899 distinct ImageMso names from the various sources. I hope others can find this useful.

[Microsoft Office Icons (ImageMSO) Gallery & Extraction](https://imagemso.codeplex.com/)

[image: ImageMSO Gallery on Microsoft Excel 2013 running Windows 8]

Comment: When I open excel it asks me if I want to enable the addin for just the session or keep it disabled. I enable it and it's not there. I go into the addin options and it's not listed there as enabled or disabled.

Comment: It adds button INSERT tab, but clicking it does nothing (MSO2013x86)

Comment: Do you have any worksheets open? For some reason in Excel 2013 the add in window won't appear unless there's a worksheet open somewhere. Try creating a new worksheet then click again.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose the first answer meant to say, that the icons are only meant to be used within Office; that is with Office add-ins and such.

They can be referred with Office Fluent UI definition XML for example. So the distribution form serves as visible "Ahh I want that icon in my add-in" reaction and then choosing the specified ID to use in "imageMso" attribute.

Like this (see proper full XML in Office Fluent UI customization)

```
<button id="Button1" imageMso="HappyFace" size="" label="Large Button Face" onAction="HandleOnAction" />
```

Comment: If you have an addin the imageMso tag is only available for custom ribbon/context menu items, not a button on a winform for example.

Answer (score 5):

[This article](http://hintdesk.com/c-print-all-ms-office-imagemso-to-files/comment-page-1/#comment-29543) contains code that worked for me. They even linked the outputted icon sets in transparent PNGs in the article too, so that you don't need to run the code. I've copied the transparent PNG's links from the article below.

[Images 1](http://www.mediafire.com/download/7md1sfpn0q7wmh7/Office+2010+Icon+Gallery+Files.zip)

[Images 2](https://app.box.com/s/e966ab628bb4b090cd2a)

**Note:**

Although the icons had a transparent background only the image within the icon was transparent, I had to go into Photoshop and remove the white background manually at the top and bottom. Here's an example:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Go to tab "File"
On the left panel you'll see list of backstage tabs

Answer (score 0):

From this [post](http://hintdesk.com/c-print-all-ms-office-imagemso-to-files/), there are 2 download links for all ImageMso of Office 2010/2013. There is also source code so that we can extract Icons ourselves with different size.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I miss an "how to use" not "how to view" answer.

In Visual Studio 2015 you can just assign the name (or ID - shown in the docx File right below the pictures) to the "OfficeImageId" Property. This Property is for example available in Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonEditBox or .RibbonButton.