# C++ Builder/Delphi TRibbon Office icons list

Tags: delphi, icons, c++builder, ribbon, vcl

I'm new to C++ Builder. Now I'm creating a ribbon with action manager and image list. Action icons are small and not looks like Office buttons

[image: small icons]

but they must be like this

[image]

how can I do it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan then icons become pixelated

Comment: You need the button size to match the icon size. The Emba ribbon is not the best choice anyway. Better to use the official ms control.

Answer (score 1):

So, I thought, that in Delphi standard action icons must be as Office Ribbon icons.

But now I know, that you have to get this icons from another way to use them :) I used this tool https://imagemso.codeplex.com/ (["Office 2010 Add-In: Icons Gallery" - How to extract icons from backstage tab (docx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623819/office-2010-add-in-icons-gallery-how-to-extract-icons-from-backstage-tab-d))

And for different sizes you must make two `TImageList` components. one of them will store 16x16 icons, another will store 32x32 icons. If you using png, you must set `ColorDepth = cd32Bit`, `DrawingStyle = dsTransparent`.

Then in ribbon's `TActionManager` you must set `Images` and `LargeImages` properties to this image lists.

Then we setting ImageIndex property of `TAction`s.

Finally, when you create ribbon item by moving `TAction` to ribbon group area and getting `TActionClientItem`, if you want big icon, you must set `CommandProperties.ButtonSize` to `bsLarge`.

Maybe it is very simple, but I passed a lot of time to learn all of it.